# how to return true or false when i wont know until the callback is performed

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js

I have an ajax function inside of a function in a backbone model. I want the function fetchByFBID to return true or false based on what the data returned consists of. But since I dont know what the data is until the callback is performed, I do not know how to return true or false in that function. Any tips?

```
  var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/API/users',
    defaults: { 
      "fbID": "", 
      "firstName": "", 
      "lastName": "", 
      "gender": "", 
      "email": "",
      "site": ""
    },
    fetchByFBID: function(fbID) {
      var that = this;
      console.log(this);
      $.ajax({url: "/API/users/fbID/"+fbID, type: 'GET', success: function(data) {
        if(data === "false") {  
          return false;
        } else {
          that.set(JSON.parse(data));
          return true;
        }
      }});
    }
  });
```

To call the function I simply do:

```
var fbUser = new UserModel();
fbUser.fetchByFBID(response.id);
```

My goal is to be able to do something like:

```
var fbUser = new UserModel();
if(fbUser.fetchByFBID(response.id))
  //do something
else
  //do something else
```

Comment: You can't, it's asynchronous. JavaScript does not `wait`

Comment: How are you calling this? You'll need to refactor this.

Comment: check the edit, added a little more information. And if there is a completely different way i should be doing this I can definitely change it. Pretty new to MVC

Comment: `fetchByFBID` needs to take two callback functions to handle the return: one would get called on success and one on failure. Alternatively, use one callback for both conditions and pass it the true or false "return" value as an argument. This is pretty standard AJAX stuff: callbacks and more callbacks.

Comment: @muistooshort alternatively, return a `promise`. This seems to be gaining popularity anyways.

Comment: @Jan: Yeah, that works too. Pretty much the same set up though, just a question of where the logic makes more sense.

Comment: @muistooshort I wouldn't really recommend your second approach - forcing a `complete` callback instead of a `success/fail` pair.

Comment: @Jan: The single callback approach seems to be popular with the node.js people, the multiple callback approach is more jQuery-ish. I think it is a matter of taste, local conventions, and (as usual) what makes the most sense in the specific situation.

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks for the information. What are the benefits of the single-entry-point approach? All I can think of is reduced chance of unneccessary code duplication (Which _is_ important :-) )

Comment: @Jan: I think it is mostly a matter of preference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either :

- add a callback as an argument to your function, and asynchronously call it with true or false

  ```
  var fbUser = new UserModel();
  fbUser.fetchByFBID(response.id, function (result) {
    if (result) {
       // do something
    } else {
      // do something else
    }
  );
  ```

This should be as easy as

```
   fetchByFBID: function(fbID, callback) {

   .... do your work .... 
     if(data === "false") {  
      callback.call(null,true); // or callback(true), callback.call(whatever, true), etc...
    } else {
      that.set(JSON.parse(data));
      callback.call(null,false);
    }
```

- instead of true or false, make your function return a "promise", so that you can write something along the lines of

  ```
  var fbUser = new UserModel();
  fbUser.fetchByFBID(response.id).whenDone(function (result) {
    if (result) {
        // do something
     } else {
        // do something else
     }
  });
  ```

Comment: Option #4 return the _real_ jQuery promise (the one with success/error/always functionality) instead of your own. I vote for this one.

Comment: @JanDvorak true, though I tend to prefer having only one callback for the 'normal' course of actions, and using extra callbacks for error / exceptional cases only. (Of course, if in this case, returning false means an error occured, than two callbacks would do the trick.)

Comment: @Jan: But then you're back to the single callback stuff since the success or failure of the call is embedded in the returned data rather than the HTTP status code. But, of course, it depends on what makes sense in the specific case :)

Comment: @JanDvorak sure for the jquery promise, but I don't know the syntax by heart myself, and I wanted to emphasise the need to refactor caller code anyway ;) !

Comment: awesome, I will look into adding a callback as a parameter and calling it from the ajax success callback. Never created my own callback, but shouldn't be too hard

Comment: @TroyCosentino a callback is nothing but a function that you store somewhere (most likely, close over or just pass along) and ... call later :-)

Comment: I figured it was pretty simple, didn't realize it would be quite that simple. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: sorry, what exactly is the first parameter in call?

Comment: @TroyCosentino it's the execution context of the function, which means the value that the 'this' keyword will have inside the function. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: ahh awesome, i was reading that article before but couldn't quite piece it together.

Answer (score 0):

I would add additional  hidden or any div. In callback function set its content to 'true' or 'false' or any other values you like and use events to notify the operations that you get the ajax answer already. 
This solution use kind of observer pattern.

Comment: Not sure why the handlers should hang on a dom node. However, this _will_ work.

Comment: You can also use some repetable js function that will check the field content in every second or two...